# Why doesn't Windows Service work properly with System.Timers.Timer or System.Windows.Forms.Timer

Tags: .net, windows-services, timer

I have been recently challenged with writing a Windows Service. I needed to periodically request a URL and check its availability. For this I decided to initialize a timer in `OnStart` method of the service and do all the work in `timer_Tick` event.

My first approach was using `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` and its `Tick` event. I chose for it, because of the tutorial that I was reading. Somehow I could not make the service work. It installed and started without problems, but it would not fire the event (I attached the debugger to the process and saw that it was not fired). I thought that maybe using Forms timer in Windows service is not a good idea, so I decided to switch to `System.Timers.Timer` and utilize its `Elapsed` event. This did not work either. I tried both mentioned approaches in a Windows Forms application and they both worked.

After some digging, I found this site: http://weblogs.asp.net/sibrahim/archive/2004/01/13/58429.aspx on which the blogger advices to utilize yet another timer: `System.Threading.Timer`. I changed the approach for the third time and *BOOM* it started working like a charm.

My question is: why can't I use the other timers in Windows services and why is it so difficult to find an information about it?

Comment: I now found this article comparing different .NET timers. Definitely worth reading: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx

Comment: The `System.Threading.Timer` is the only one that worked for me in `Windows Server 2008 R2` though Timers.Timer worked in my `Windows 7 laptop`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` timer uses the message pump of the UI to marshal the tick event, a service doesn't run a message pump by default so without a little extra work the `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` timers will not work.

The `System.Timers.Timer` is a server-based timer and raises an event on the thread you create it on (I think). If this isn't working, perhaps you aren't starting the timer or the timer runs on a thread that immediately ends (as in, nothing is keeping the thread alive so it finishes).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx

The `System.Threading.Timer` timer uses a callback that runs on a `ThreadPool` thread and isn't tied to the message pump at all, hence this worked.

When you run `Application.Run(myForm)` in a WinForms project, that call also runs up the message pump, this manages UI messages. The windows timer you mention is a UI component and expects the message pump to be running in order to cause the tick event to occur on the UI thread.

Take a look here for running a message pump in a Windows Service:

[Message pump in .NET Windows service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2443867/message-pump-in-net-windows-service)

Further reading:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/842793

In conclusion, I'd just go with the `System.Threading.Timer` class.

Comment: Both those timers run code on a threadpool thread.  Having the event/callback run on the same thread that created the timer requires magic.  The kind of magic a message pump supplies.

Answer (score 1):

refer to these questions

[Windows Service System.Timers.Timer not firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8466597/windows-service-system-timers-timer-not-firing)

[Does the System.Windows.Forms.Timer run on a different thread than the UI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694469/does-the-system-windows-forms-timer-run-on-a-different-thread-than-the-ui)

[Timer tick event is not called in windows service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4561479/timer-tick-event-is-not-called-in-windows-service)

these might answer your query.

Comment: If there are duplicates, you can flag the question itself with it.